# Why is gzip slow despite CPU and hard drive performance not being maxed out?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, gzip, buffer

I have some JSON files, 20 GB each, that I want to compress with `gzip`:

```
gzip file1.json
```

This takes up one full CPU core, all fine.

It processes around 25 MB/s (checked in `atop`), my hard drive can read 125 MB/s and I have 3 free processor cores, so I expect to get a speed-up when compressing multiple files in parallel. So I run in other terminals:

```
gzip file2.json
gzip file3.json
gzip file4.json
```

Surprisingly, my throughput does not increase; CPU is around 25% on each core, and my HD still only reads at 25 MB/s.

Why and how to address it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found it out:

The reason is that `gzip` operates on (in terms of CPU speed vs HD seek speed these days) **extremely low buffer sizes**.

It reads a few KB from from the input file, compresses it, and flushes it to the output file. Given the fact that this requires a hard drive seek, only a few operations can be done per seconds.

The reason my performance did not scale is because already one `gzip` was seeking like crazy.

---

I worked around this by using the unix [`buffer`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/buffer) utility:

```
buffer -s 100000 -m 10000000 -p 100 < file1.json | gzip > file1.json.gz
```

By buffering a lot of input before sending it to gzip, the number of small seeks can be dramatically reduced. The options:

- `-s` and `-m` are to specify the size of the buffer (I *believe* it is in KB, but not sure)
- `-p 100` makes sure that the data is only passed to gzip once the buffer is 100% filled

Running four of these in parallel, I could get 4 * 25 MB/s throughput, as expected.

---

I still wonder why gzip doesn't allow to increase the buffer size - this way, it is pretty useless if run on a spinning disk.

**EDIT**: I tried out a few more compression programs behaviour:

- `bzip2` only processes 2 MB/s due to its stronger / more CPU intensive compression
- `lzop` seems to allow larger buffers: 70 MB/s per core, and 2 cores can max out my HD without over-seeking

Comment: Can `dd` do the same?

Comment: @SimonKuang I suspect that `dd` can do the same with its `bs=` option, yes.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting coincidence that for a single file the block size happened to fully utilize both a single CPU core and a drive's IOPS.

Answer (score 5):

After looking at the first five or so lectures in the MIT OpenCourseware for 6.172: "Performance Engineering of Software Systems", I ran the Linux performance analyzer 'perf' on a moderately large test file. The result appears to show pipeline stalls where one instruction has to wait for the result of a preceding one.

```
       │         while (lookahead != 0) {                                                                
       │             /* Insert the string window[strstart .. strstart+2] in the                          
       │              * dictionary, and set hash_head to the head of the hash chain:                     
       │              */                                                                                 
       │             INSERT_STRING(strstart, hash_head);                                                 
  2.07 │       movzbl 0x8096d82(%edx),%eax                                                               
  3.99 │       mov    %edx,%ebp                                                                          
       │       shl    $0x5,%ecx                                                                          
  0.03 │       and    $0x7fff,%ebp                                                                       
  1.94 │       xor    %ecx,%eax                                                                          
  1.43 │       and    $0x7fff,%eax                                                                       
  2.01 │       mov    %eax,0x805e588                                                                     
  2.40 │       add    $0x8000,%eax                                                                      
  0.88 │       movzwl 0x8062140(%eax,%eax,1),%ecx                                                        
 23.79 │       movzwl %cx,%edi                                                                           
       │             /* Find the longest match, discarding those <= prev_length.
```

The second last instruction is copying to `%ecx` and the last one has to wait (stalling the pipeline) until the `%cx` register has data ready to use. This pipeline stall holds up the containing loop.

This is a result of some really obscure 'old-school' C programming style.

Answer (score 1):

A tip that might take it to yet another level of speed on a multi-core/hyperthreading CPU:
*(assuming Ubuntu)*

> sudo apt-get install moreutils

moreutils contains among other things "gnu parallel" - which has a lot of options to help use more of your CPU.